# Identifying a load-bearing wall

Tags: load-bearing

Can I just triple check to get your views on whether the indicated wall in this house floor plan (between kitchen and diner on ground floor) is a load-bearing wall or not? Very much appreciated.

[image: house plans]

[image: foundation piles]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It requires an engineer or architect's professional opinion and is not suitable for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not a bearing wall, but there is a "double stud" (post) required in the wall line to support the "beam that supports the roof" that is in the second floor exterior wall. Very unusual.

This post (double stud) is important because it's noted on the second floor plan too. So, the double stud is to extend up to the roof level and align with the double stud on the first floor level. We don't create a separate structural system (like this double stud system / beam system) we just "up-size" the floor joists to support the second floor loading and the second floor exterior wall load and whatever roof loads too.

First, you'll notice there are parallel walls on each side of the kitchen and dining that align with the second floor (although the second floor is slightly narrower.) This allows all the framing to span from wall to wall and transfer the loads to the foundation. The wall between the kitchen / dining runs perpendicular to the floor joists and roof trusses so it will not be a bearing wall, but has a "double stud" note in it. So, you can remove the WALL but not the POST (double stud).

Second, if you look close, you'll see notes and arrows on the drawings that refer to, "300 x 50 joists". This refers to the size of the joists and the direction the joists are to span. (We Americans never learned the metric system.) As you can see, the floor joists rests on the walls perpendicular to the kitchen / dining wall. So, again, it's not a bearing wall.

Also, it is not a "shear wall". A shear wall is used to keep the building "stiff" and not allow the structure to sway or turn into a parallelogram. I live in a high wind area, as I suspect you do too, and I'm very interested in horizontal thrusts on buildings as well as vertical loads.

You can remove this wall (but not the double stud) and sleep well at nights or not worry when you're out windsurfing.

Note: If you look close at the North East elevation, you'll notice there is no double studs required on the left side of the drawing, only on the right side. Yet, it has the same identical roof structure. (Hmmm...unless there is a vaulted ceiling on the right side.   Is there?)

Comment: Oh, and it would be great to see the "Foundation Plan" to confirm my analysis.

Comment: Cheers Lee. I've added in the foundation plan too. 
My concerns around the wall are due to us looking to buy this place, and the previous owner has already had that wall removed ... we were wondering if they needed local authority consent to do so or not. Were informed that as it was not load-bearing, the work didn't need consent. To quote: "The wall removed was non-bearing but I have replaced it with a 300 x 100 beam and 100 x 100 posts at ends all tied into existing frames accordingly"

Comment: The good news is that there isn't anything on the Foundation Plan that indicates the double stud (post) is important. There isn't a footing or extra support on the Foundation Plan that would indicate the roof load needs to be transferred down to the foundation. You don't have snow where you live, so not having the beam and post (double stud) does not surprise me. (The beam and post are strictly for support for the roof.) However, I'm familiar with your countries code and structural requirements. So, I'd have the local Building Official confirm that it's not required.

Comment: Here, we are not allowed to make changes to the plans during construction unless the Architect or Building Official approves it in advance. May they have record of why they allowed the change.